# Set custom port when starting symfony local web server

Tags: symfony4, local-web-server

I want to start a server with `symfony server:start` using the port that is set in my .env file. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 16):

For anyone stumbling here from google like I did, use the flag `--port=PORTNUMBER`

Example:

```
symfony server:start --port=8080
```

OR

```
php bin/console server:start --port=8080
```

The help page documentation states this like so:

> --port=value           Preferred HTTP port [default: 8000]

Answer (score 2):

```
php bin/console server:start --help
```

Gives the info you want

```
Usage:
  server:start [options] [--] [<addressport>]

Arguments:
  addressport            The address to listen to (can be address:port, address, or port)
```

So type

```
Change the default address and port by passing them as an argument:

php bin/console server:start 127.0.0.1:8080
```